# Symbol not found : string.size() Java Syntax Error

Tags: java, string, size

```
  String[] words = text.split("\\s+");
  for(int j = 0; j < words.size(); j++) {
       System.out.println(j)
   }
```

I am getting an error in the above for loop:

HelloWorld.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        for(int j = 0; j < words.size(); j++) {
                                ^
  symbol:   method size()
  location: variable words of type String[]
1 error

Not sure what is wrong syntatically?

Comment: It actually tells you exactly what the error is: there is no size() method on an array. To get the "size" of an array, read the .length property: words.length.

Comment: Thanks! fixed. I was trying words.length(), but when I tried words.length it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `words.size()` to `words.length`.
because array doesn't have `size()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call `size()` on an array, array has a `length` property (not a `size`). Also, I think you wanted to print `words[j]` (not `j`). Finally, you could use a [`for each` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like,

```
String[] words = text.split("\\s+");
for(String word : words) {
   System.out.println(word);
}
```

Or, you could use [`Arrays.toString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28Object[]%29) and skip the loop

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(text.split("\\s+")));
```